# Absolute position of text in div that is centered in browser window

Tags: html, alignment

It is easy to absolutely position text relative to a div when the div is aligned with the left side of a browser window. The width of the browser window can change size and the text stays in the correct position. But I have a fixed width web page that is always centered in the browser window. I have a div that is centered on the web page regardless of the width of the browser window. This div contains an image. I need to absolutely position text on top of the image. My code is:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div> <img style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%; display:block;" src="../../assets/logos/skitours_title_756w_100h.gif" alt="Website logo">
        <div class="tour_title"> <h3>This is the title</h3> </div>
    </div>
</div>

#wrapper {
    width:756px;
    height:auto;
    margin: auto auto; 
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

.tour_title {
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#696969;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:500px;
    top:40px;
    left:20px;
}
```

That results in the image being centered on the web page regardless of the width of the browser window.

But the absolute positioning of the text (tour_title) is relative to the left side of the browser window, not the image. How do I correct the code so that the text is relative to the webpage regardless of the width of the browser window?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to make the text relative to the **image**.
If that's the case, you should:

1. Make the wrapper position: relative so the "absolute" text references it instead of the browser/webpage.
2. Make the text div text-align:center; and width:100%; for it to align at the center of the wrapper.
3. Make the top: whatever you wish.
   Something like this:

> ```
> #wrapper {
>     width:756px;
>     height:auto;
>     margin: auto auto; 
>     margin-bottom:5px;
>     border-style:solid;
>     position:relative;
> }
>
> .tour_title {
>     font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
>     font-size:20px;
>     font-weight:bold;
>     color:#ff00ff;
>     position: absolute;
>     text-align:center;
>     width:100%;
>     top: 50%;
> }
> ```